# Making a folder need root permanently

Tags: permissions

I want to make a directory need root to access. I tried

```
chmod 000 /path/to/directory
```

And it works but the change is easily revertable. How do i make it permambent?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrong command. You need to change owner and group to 'root'.

```
chown root:root /path/to/directory
```

And if you want to harden it even more put the 'immutable' on it with

```
chattr -i /path/to/directory
```

(only 'root' can set this back).

---

```
chmod 000 /path/to/directory
```

only removes permissions but it is still owned by the user (and the group it belongs to). It does not make it only for 'root'. Removing permissions from a directory makes in non-executable and for someone to enter it you need that set.

Answer (score 7):

You not only need to change the permissions on this particular folder, you as well have to change the ownership of it. And up to it `chmod 000` is a bad idea, because it allows no one to enter it, use `700` instead. Just see my example:

```
chmod 700 /path/folder
sudo chown -R root:root /path/folder
```

[See here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) for more information on file permissions.